# Spark shuffling data before insert

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

`CalcDf().show` results into 13 stages(0-12) +1(13) for the `show` itself.
[image]

When I try to write the result to table, I assume there should only be 13 stages(0-12), instead I see and additional stage(13). Where does it come from and what does it do? I'm not performing any repartition or other operation that would require a shuffle. As far as I understand spark should just write 1100 files into the table, but it's not what's happening.

```
CalcDf()
.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.insertInto("tn")
```

[image]
CalcDf() logic

```
val dim = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
spark.table("dim")
.as[Dim]
.map(r => r.id-> r.col)
.collect().toMap
)

spark.table("table")
.as[CustomCC]
.groupByKey(_.id)
.flatMapGroups{case(k, iterator) => CustomCC.mapRows(iterator, dim)}
.withColumn("time_key", lit("2021-07-01"))
```

Comment: add details about table `tn`, is it partitioned ?

Comment: @vikas it's partitioned. But the key hardcoded to be the same for every row `.withColumn("time_key", lit("2021-07-01"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous stage #12 has done shuffle write so any subsequent stage will have to read data from this via shuffle read (which you notice in #13).

Why is there an additional stage ?

because stage 12 has shuffle write and not an Output

for understanding of stage #12 please give information about how CalDf is built.

**EDIT**

groupByKey will do shuffle write, for getting same ids on single executor JVM.

stage 13 is reading this shuffled data and computing map operation after.

difference in task count can be attributed to action.
In show(), it hasn't read whole shuffled data. Maybe because it displays 20 rows (default)
whereas in insertInto(...), it is operating on whole data so reading all.

stage #13 is not just because it is writing files but it is actually doing computation.